# 403 Error - Javascript AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an existing AJAX GET script that is working and passing data via the URL back to my PHP code.

Due to the data I now want to send, I want to change the AJAX to a POST.

I have created some data in the below JSON format

```
var lead = {
    "email"     : document.getElementById('emailAddress').value,
    "source"    : document.getElementById('source').value,
    "purpose"   : document.getElementById('need').value,
   "amount" : amount,
    "lvr": lvr};
```

This is then passing to the below function

```
var string =  JSON.stringify(lead); 
var uri = "http://127.0.0.1/HomeLoans/ajax/ajaxcreateLead/";

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        alert("YA");
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST", uri, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
xmlhttp.send(string);
```

Chrome is giving me a 403 Forbidden error and I can't seem to workout where I have gone wrong.

[Chrome Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JEld.png)

Thanks!! :)

Comment: have you tried to execute this uri using a curl method or something like this? Please add more info about te service that you are trying to call.

Comment: There is not currently any service at the other end, just just been trying to get the AJAX call working first before I build the rest.  AJAX is very new to me.  I haven't tried to use CURL for this but I am using service for another function which works find.

Comment: "403 Forbidden" means you have some `.htaccess` rule blocking that path

Comment: 2hrs of my life wasted, sorry guys.  The leading forward slash was the prob.!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Apache, put in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Allow From All
```